# After Implement Progress Dialog project is running very slow

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have implement progress bar but, after implement this progress bar is spinning in long term, , please help why is this going very slow. if i will remove progress dialog, it take only 30 seconds, after implement progress it takes more than 60 seconds ..

i use this code

```
 class ProgressBarshow extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
     private ProgressDialog pdia;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdia = new ProgressDialog(Cases.this);
        pdia.setMessage("Loading...");
        pdia.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(Cases.this,url);
        return null;
    }
            @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
         pdia.dismiss();
        listshowcase.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to update ui in doInBackground? If so you should not

Comment: i don't want to update ui, @Raghunandan

Comment: I guess your doInbackground computation is taking longer time. It has nothing to with progress dialog. Quoting from docs "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask".

Comment: i was using this , but with this also taken more time that's y i have remove this ..........protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... progress) {
   // setting progress percentage
           
            Save.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
                }
              });
            
            
       }

Comment: i don't think that is cause of slowdown in this case. Its what your doing in doinbackground, ie the computation that is taking longer time